# Socket.IO authorization without refresh

Tags: node.js, socket.io, authorization

On the first call to localhost it sends index.html and tries to authorize.
Authorization is of course not approved. After the user has then filled out a form in index.html "app.post ('/ login' ..." is executed.

What I now want is that the authorization after login will be executed once and the client with Socket.IO connects.

Is that possible? Or do I have to refresh the page after login on the client side?

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    req.session.status = {
        test:111
    };
    res.end();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.set('authorization', function(req, callback) {
    console.log("hi");
    // check if user is logged, if yes connect with socket.io
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
});
```